# Laravel 5.2 Auth relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm having a problem with a relationship through the Users model when using the Auth class. The relationship I think is suppose to be $this->hasMany('App\Product') and also will it return the newly saved id back to a variable through this method. When I try to use Auth::user()->products()->save($product) I get the following error. I'm learning Laravel 5.2 and I don't know how this code should work could some give me some help

```
FatalErrorException in ProductsController.php line 32:
Call to a member function products() on a non-object
```

UserModel:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Zizaco\Entrust\Traits\EntrustUserTrait;
use App\Product;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use EntrustUserTrait;

    protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];


    public function products() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }
}
```

ProductModel:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $table = "products";

    protected $fillable = ['category_id', 'user_id', 'supplier_id', 'title', 'price'];

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

ProductsController:

```
class ProductsController extends Controller
{

    public function create() {

        $categories = Category::lists('name', 'id')->toArray(); 
        $suppliers = Supplier::lists('company_name', 'id')->toArray();

        return view('products.create', compact('suppliers', 'categories'));
    }

    public function store() {

        $product = new Product(Request::all());

        $id = Auth::user()->products()->save($product);

        return redirect('admin/products');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think the user is not logged in thats why Auth::user() is null

Comment: You where right I put my routes in the wrong place thanks for that cheers

Answer (score 1):

`Auth::user()` only returns a `User` object if a user is logged in. You should add some checking code such as:

```
if (! Auth::check()) {
    // redirect to the login page, etc.
}
```

to prevent it from being null.

Comment: How do you add Auth checking in the routes

Comment: don't worry I got it's 'middleware' => 'auth'